# Espresso test recorder adds too big sleeps

Tags: android, android-espresso

While recording tests with the help of Espresso recorder from Android Studio 3.0.1 too long Threed.sleep() are added.They can reach 30 mins (1800000ms). Is it possible to customize it somehow, because actually, 5 seconds is more than enough for app to load everything.

Update 1.
After I tried to record test with the help of Espresso Test recorder I got an information message, that some dependencies are missing in my gradle file. After I agreed to add them, the following were added to build.gradle

```
    androidTestCompile 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-contrib:2.2.2', {
    exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-v4'
    exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'design'
    exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'recyclerview-v7'
}
```

At the same time, there were already following dependencies, which allowed me to create and run tests manully:

```
androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.1'
androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.1'
androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:rules:1.0.1'
```

And now, when I record tests enormously long (e.g. up to Thread.sleeps(1800000)) are added to the moments, when app is loading. If they are replaced, tests can run successfully

Comment: Could you show us a code example?

Comment: @ChristianNeverdal, thanks for your reply. Do you need code of auto generated Espresso tests?

Comment: Explain how you're using the framework, and any output/results described in detail.

Comment: Maybe you can open the generated file and change the `Thread.sleep();` with your own value

Comment: @MickaelB. this works perfectly, but I would like let testers without sufficient background record the tests for me.

Comment: @ChristianNeverdal, updated

Comment: What is the procedure you are using when you are recording these tests?

Comment: Android Studio -> Run -> Record Espresso Test -> Use my app as usual, @ChristianNeverdal

Comment: Are the sleeps always big and always the same value?

Comment: @ChristianNeverdal, they are always big, but not the same. The biggest value is 1800000

Comment: Are the numbers always round? If so, that hints at a configuration option or something - after all, a user won't exactly wait 1800000 ms before the next click. :)